# adding mouseover effect to a button with Image in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, styles

I am having a button with Image on it as follows:

```
<Button Width="22" Height="22" Command="{Binding PreviousCommand}">                               
  <Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
      <Image Source="C:\Users\abcdef\Desktop\Slide-To-Left-Arrow-24.png"></Image>                            
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Button.Template>
  <Button.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Up" Command="{Binding PreviousCommand}" Modifiers="Alt+Shift" />
  </Button.InputBindings>
</Button>
```

I want to apply some mouse over effect to recognise button is clickable/focusable.
I tried adding trigger as follows but its not working:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
  <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"> 
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" /> 
  </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Its not working. what I need to do? please help me out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your control template consists *only* of an Image at this point, so there is nothing that you can change the background on (through your trigger).  If you'd like to add a background change, you'll need to expand your `ControlTemplate` a little.  Try something like this:

```
<Button.Template>
  <ControlTemplate>
    <Grid x:Name="bg">
      <Image Margin="4" Source="C:\Users\dheeraj.dilip.awale\Desktop\Slide-To-Left-Arrow-24.png"></Image>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"> 
           <Setter Target="bg" Property="Background" Value="Black" /> 
        </Trigger>
     </ControlTemplate.Triggers>                            
  </ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>
```

This is just a *very simple* example of how you can utilize the trigger you've shown above.  All this does is add a `Grid` under the image and a `Margin` to the image so that part of the `Grid` is visible.  It then uses the `Target` property of the `Setter` to assign the `Background` of the `Grid` when the user hovers over the button.  You can certainly do much more with your `ControlTemplate` to provide other types of visual cues, but hopefully this will get you started.

Comment: thanks. but its giving compile time error on Target="mygrid".

Comment: Do you have an element in your template somewhere named "mygrid"?  I don't see that name in your post or my answer.  You'll need to make sure the `Target` in the `Trigger` `Setter` matches the `x:Name` of the `Grid` in the template.

Comment: Works like a charm, even if I had to set TargetName instead of Target in the setter