# My button-style doesn't show my background image on MouseOver

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

I have create a style for a button like this

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="BoutonRessources">
       <Setter Property="Width" Value="18" />
       <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,0,-2,0" />
       <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Clear" />
       <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
       <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
       <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
       <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
       <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
       <Style.Triggers>
           <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Background">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <ImageBrush ImageSource="BoutonToolbarSelected.png"/>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
               <Setter Property="Height"  Value="22"/>
               <Setter Property="Width"  Value="32"/>
           </Trigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
```

My button appear on my screen but when the mouse is over the button, it don't show my "BoutonToolbarSelected.png". Do you know why ?

**Here is how i call my button :**

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource BoutonRessources}" >
    <Image Source= "xRtDiva_XWPF_TBR_PREMIER.PNG_IMAGES.png" Height="18"/>
</Button>
```

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: What happends when keep the Button content empty? (removing the image)

Comment: On my Style, or on my call ? Actually, on Mouse Over,it show the standard MouseOverButton, not the BoutonToolbarSelected.png

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808955/adding-mouseover-effect-to-a-button-with-image-in-xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you set `<Image Source= "xRtDiva_XWPF_TBR_PREMIER.PNG_IMAGES.png" Height="18"/>` as Content of your button, the background will hide behind it.

You could change your trigger to:

```
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="BoutonToolbarSelected.png"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Height"  Value="22"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width"  Value="32"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="xRtDiva_XWPF_TBR_PREMIER.PNG_IMAGES.png"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Height"  Value="18"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
```